# Why is IsGenericParameter false for a generic parameter out T

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a method defined like this:

```
public bool TryGetProperty<T>(string name, out T value)
```

Looking at the `MethodInfo` for this method, I find

```
methodInfo.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.IsGenericParameter
```

is `false`.  I expected it to be `true`, because the second parameter has a type of `T`.  (On the other hand, `methodInfo.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.ContainsGenericParameters` is `true`.)

Why is `IsGenericParameter` false in this case?  And what is the correct way to verify that the second parameter has a type of `T`.  For instance, I'm trying to find the correct method by filtering the results of `Type.GetMethods()`.

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the result of methodInfo.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.IsGenericType ?

Comment: @jbl, It's also `false`

Comment: In C# terminology, the parameter type is `T`, but for IL, it isn't, it's `ref T` (the `ref` is part of the type) with a custom attribute `Out`.

Comment: try by removing out and then try it, what is the result tell me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The parameter type isn't `T`, it's what IL and Reflection call `T&` (`ref T`). It's correct that `IsGenericParameter` returns `false`: for by-ref types, you first have to get the type being referred to.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class TestClass
{
    public void TestMethod<T>(out T something)
    {
        something = default(T);
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var method = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("TestMethod");
        var parameter = method.GetParameters()[0];
        Console.WriteLine("parameter.ParameterType.IsGenericParameter: " + parameter.ParameterType.IsGenericParameter);
        Console.WriteLine("parameter.ParameterType.IsByRef: " + parameter.ParameterType.IsByRef);
        Console.WriteLine("parameter.ParameterType.GetElementType().IsGenericParameter: " + parameter.ParameterType.GetElementType().IsGenericParameter);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
parameter.ParameterType.IsGenericParameter: False
parameter.ParameterType.IsByRef: True
parameter.ParameterType.GetElementType().IsGenericParameter: True
```